# Saving null value to decimal field using apex

Tags: apex, exception, decimal

I just wanted to check is it possible to save empty value or null value to a decimal field using apex.

Let us take that there is a number field by name Count__c, which needs to be set as blank when certain conditions met. I can do it by workflow field update for new records, but i want to update the existing records. So just  thought of writing a script in console, but when i assign a blank value to that field and try to execute it gives me exception that we cannot assign a blank value.

If i can do it via workflow field update why cannot we do it using apex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you probably did something like this:

```
record.Count__c = '';
```

This is not a blank value, it's an empty *String*. To make a field blank, set it to "null":

```
record.Count__c = null;
```